# change the content of a UIWebView from another Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview

I have a TableViewController which is supposed to load a ViewController with a WebView in it when I select a cell.

Here's the code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PostViewController *postViewController = [[PostViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PostViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [postViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.fr"]]]
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:postViewController animated:YES];

    [PostViewController release];

}
```

The problem is that the ViewController is loaded but nothing happens in the WebView.
When I debug the program I can see that the WebView's address is 0x0 so I guess something's wrong.
Is it because I try to modify the content of the WebView before its parent ViewController is loaded ?

I guess another way to do it properly would be to pass the URL to the ViewController and then to call loadRequest on the WebView from inside the viewWillAppear method.
But I need to understand why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Where is your web view initialised?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not initialized at all. But it seems like it is not necessary in this case, because I tried BuildSucceeded's solution and it works without initializing it. The WebView is declared as an outlet of my PostViewController and it is linked to a WebView control in PostViewController.xib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x0` is the address of `nil`, meaning that your web view has not been initialized at this point.

If you're creating your web view in the `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` methods of `PostViewController`, then calling `setNeedsLayout` immediately after initialization will force its creation:

```
PostViewController *postViewController = [[PostViewController alloc] init ...
[postViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
```

Otherwise, these methods will not be called until your view is displayed.

Comment: And I can't interact with the WebView once it is displayed ?

Comment: Once it is displayed you can interact with it as usual. Since you haven't elaborated on your setup, I created a test project assuming the web view's initialization in `loadView` and confirmed that it behaves as expected.

Comment: I did give you more information under Peter Hosey's post (under your question). I will try your solution without forgetting to initialize it this time :)
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

Instead of accessing the WebView why dont you just pass the URL value to the ViewController and load the Webview in the viewDidLoad of postViewController.

In your case

```
PostViewController *postViewController = [[PostViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PostViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
postViewController.urlString = @"http://www.google.fr";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:postViewController animated:YES];

[PostViewController release];
```

In your postViewController.h declare the urlString with properties and synthesize in the .m file

Now in your viewDidLoad

```
//Alloc init your webview here
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about in the last paragraph of my post (as an alternate solution) and it works perfectly. But I also needed to understand why it didn't work the other way (but I guess jnic answered that part of the question). Anyway, thanks for your time.